# Get partial results of map after exception

Tags: clojure

How can you get the partial results from a map when an exception happens during execution?

i.e

```
(let [numbers [3 3 0 3]
  results (map #(/ 3 %) numbers)]
 results)
```

and return:

```
[3 3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
(let [numbers [3 3 0 3]
      results (map
               #(try (/ 3 %)
                     (catch Exception e e))
                   numbers)]
  (take-while #(not (instance? Exception %)) results))
```

Answer (score 3):

since thrown exception unwinds the stack up to the place where exception is caught (in your case it goes up to the top level), you can't operate on `result` after if. What you can do, is to manually put some value where the error was caught:

```
(let [numbers [3 3 0 3]
      results (take-while number?
                          (map #(try
                                  (/ 3 %)
                                  (catch Throwable ex :error))
                               numbers))]
  results)
```

Comment: I'd replace `Throwable` with `Exception` here. Usually, supressing Java [`Error`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using the [cats](https://funcool.github.io/cats/latest/) library's [exception](http://funcool.github.io/cats/latest/api/cats.monad.exception.html) monad:

```
(ns your-project.core
  (:require [cats.monad.exception :as e]))

(let [numbers [3 3 0 3]
      results (->> numbers
                   (map #(e/try-on (/ 3 %))) ; wrap division result in a try
                   (take-while e/success?)   ; take values while successful
                   (mapv e/extract))]        ; unwrap the values from the trys
  results)

;; => [1 1]
```

And if you want to keep the values that come after the exception:

```
(let [numbers [3 3 0 3]
      results (->> numbers
                   (map #(e/try-on (/ 3 %)))
                   (filter e/success?)       ; filter all successful values
                   (mapv e/extract))]
  results)

;; => [1 1 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `keep`:

```
(let [numbers [3 3 0 3]]
  (keep #(try 
          (/ 3 %)
          (catch RuntimeException _ nil)) numbers))
```